# com.apple.emond keeps getting restarted

Tags: macos, launchd, osx-server

My system log tells me that the Event Monitor is constantly getting restarted and I have no clue what the actual problem might be.

system.log:

```
Oct 19 21:03:44 funkymachinename emond[51201]: SetUpLogs: uid = 0 gid = 0
Oct 19 21:03:44 funkymachinename emond[51201]: SetUpLogs: opening /Library/Logs/EventMonitor/EventMonitor.error.log
Oct 19 21:03:44 funkymachinename com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.emond): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

/Library/Logs/EventMonitor/EventMonitor.error.log:

```
Event Monitor Started 2014-10-19 20:52:02 +0200
No rules found in /private/etc/emond.d/rules/, quitting....
Event Monitor Shutdown at 2014-10-19 20:52:02 +0200
```

Checking the mentioned folder:

```
~ $ ll /private/etc/emond.d/rules/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 Aug 30 04:55 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  136 Aug 30 04:55 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  822 Aug 30 04:55 SampleRules.plist
```

I have compared that to an OSX installation that does not bail out constantly and it appears to be fine that way.

What might be the problem here?

Comment: It is still unclear to me what the actual problem was, but after rebooting the machine, everything went back to normal. Sorry for not rebooting before asking :). I will still leave this question up here for someone for give a proper answer on the root cause.

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem - basically the logs filling up with these messages. No idea if there is a performance impact. This started after upgrading to Yosemite. A reboot doesn't help in my case.  My question: is emond supposed to be started / respawned every 10 seconds or is there a configuration issue somewhere?

Comment: @RJR yes, it is supposed to get started - but only once (and keep running, hence that "d" for daemon in its name). It getting constantly respawned due to its failure to run is definitely not good.

Comment: I'd expected the daemon to shut itself down after not finding any rules to process. I guess 'no rules found' shouldn't be an error but just info.

Answer (score 9):

I saw this same behaviour after uninstalling Server.app.  I believe I have fixed it by doing the following:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.emond.plist

# remove the Server.app paths from the additionalRulesPaths array
sudo vi /etc/emond.d/emond.plist

sudo rm /var/db/emondClients/com.apple.server

sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.emond.plist
```

Comment: I was unable to run the unload and load commands on macOS Sierra due to the system files being protected. But I just removed the com.apple.server from the emondClients directory and this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 7):

Open the /private/etc/emond.d/rules/Sample.plist

Change

```
    <key>name</key>
    <string>sample rule</string>
    <key>enabled</key>
    <false/>
```

To

```
    <key>name</key>
    <string>sample rule</string>
    <key>enabled</key>
    <true/>
```

The sample rule just logs the startup time for the Event Monitoring daemon, but giving it something to do stops the constant restarts of the daemon.

Comment: While that might fix the issue for some, for me it is still set towards `<false/>` and still (after rebooting as mentioned in my comments), the daemon does not constantly get restarted.

Comment: So.... it's the best answer but you were lucky because a reboot fixed it for you?

Comment: it appears to be the only answer and frankly, IMHO it describes something that should not be needed in the first place. The default setting for that value is `false` and there most likely is a reason for that. What you describe here is a workaround, I'ld say.

Comment: The path to the file was `/private/etc/emond.d/rules/SampleRules.plist` for me on OS X 10.11. Setting `enabled` fixed it for me.